# NUSOAP SMS MULTIPLE RECIPIENTS

Tags: php, sms

Good day. Im developing a program which an admin will send notification to multiple users about the status of their request through sms. Im using NUSOAP. When i try single recipient it works properly but when i add another recipient, its not working. Please help.

**This is my code**

```
    <?php
error_reporting(0);

include_once("nusoap/lib/nusoap.php");


$client = new nusoap_client('http://iplaypen.globelabs.com.ph:1881/axis2/services/Platform');


$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';

$client->call('sendSMS', array( 'uName' => 'cs1oqie6w',
'uPin' => '21738023',
'MSISDN' => '09268791402;09156495702',
'messageString' => $_POST['sms'],
'Display' => '1',
'udh' => '',
'mwi' => '',
'coding' => '0' ),
"http://ESCPlatform/xsd");
?>
```

**Please help me i need this very badly. THANK YOU IN ADVANCE**

Comment: What is the destination number MSISDN? I tried searfhing for this api but didn't really find anything useful. Can you place a comma between those 2 numbers, or have you tried looping through the call() method for each number?

Comment: Yes it is separated with semicolon as instructed but still not working..

Comment: Did you know a better idea for this? Or SMS providers which allow multiple recipient?

Comment: just for fun try a comma. No, I don't know of a better solution other than emailing their device like: 15555555555@provider.com

Comment: i tried the comma but still not working

Comment: `'MSISDN' => array('09268791402','09156495702')` or you may have to loop through each number and without a lot of documentation on this service its pretty hard to tell